# angularJS routing using controllerAs

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am new to angularJS and trying to learn. I have `config.js` file where I am defining my config function. 
The first line of this file itself gives an error.

```
 angular.module('app').config(function($routeProvider, $locationProvider){

   $locationProvider.HTML5Mode(true);

   $routeProvider
   .when('/',{
       templateUrl: 'index.html',
       controller: 'MainController'
   })
   .when('/add', {
       templateUrl: 'add.html',
       controller: 'MainController',
       controllerAs: 'main',
   })

});
```

Below is my app.js file

```
angular.module('app',['ngRoute']);
```

In main.ctrl.js my controller function is written.

```
angular.module('app').controller("MainController", function(){
var vm = this;
vm.title = 'TV Show';
vm.searchInput = '';
vm.shows = [
    {
        title: 'Game of Thrones',
        year: 2011,
        favorite: true
    },
    {
        title: 'Walking Dead',
        year: 2010,
        favorite: false
    },
    {
        title: 'Firefly',
        year: 2002,
        favorite: true
    },
    {
        title: 'Banshee',
        year: 2013,
        favorite: true
    },
    {
        title: 'Greys Anatomy',
        year: 2005,
        favorite: false
    }
];
vm.orders = [
{
    id: 1,
    title: 'Year Ascending',
    key: 'year',
    reverse: false
},
{
    id: 2,
    title: 'Year Descending',
    key: 'year',
    reverse: true
},
{
    id: 3,
    title: 'Title Ascending',
    key: 'title',
    reverse: false
},
{
    id: 4,
    title: 'Title Descending',
    key: 'title',
    reverse: true
}
];
vm.order = vm.orders[0];
vm.new = {};
vm.addShow = function() {
vm.shows.push(vm.new);
console.log("vm.shows");
vm.new = {};
};

});
```

Now I have created a add.html page where I am trying to access my controller(MainController) but I am not able to access it. Can you please tell me that where am I going wrong

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html ng-app = 'app'>
    <head lang="en">
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Favourite TV Show</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.0-beta.2/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.25/angular-route.js"></script>
    <script src="app.js"></script>
    <script src="main.ctrl.js"></script>
</head>
<body style="width: 60%; margin:0 auto;">
    <h1>This is add page.</h1>
    <h3>Add a new TV Show</h3>
    {{main.title}}
    {{main.shows[0].title}}
    <form name="main.addForm" class="form" ng-submit="main.addShow()">

        <div class="form-group">
            <label>Title</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" ng-model="main.new.title" required />
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label>Year</label>
            <input type="number" min="1900" max="2030" class="form-control" ng-model="main.new.year" required />
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-xs-6">
                <label>Favorite: <input type="checkbox" ng-model="main.new.favorite" /></label>
            </div>
            <div class="col-xs-6">
                <button class="btn btn-success pull-right"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus-sign"></span> Add</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </form>  
</body>
</html>
```

Below is my index.html file. And I am opening add.html page when the user clicks on new show button.

```
<body ng-app="app" ng-controller="MainController as main" style="width: 60%; margin:0 auto;">
    <div class="container">
        <h1>{{main.title}}</h1>
        <div class="input-group">

            <span class="input-group-addon">
                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"></span>
            </span>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" ng-model="main.searchInput" style="width: 60%; margin:0 auto;">
        </div>
    <p>{{main.searchInput}}</p>
    </div>
    <a href=""><h3>A list of TV shows</h3></a>

    <ul class="list-group"> 
        <li class="list-group-item" ng-repeat="show in main.shows | filter:main.searchInput |  orderBy:main.order.key:main.order.reverse" >
            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-star" ng-if="show.favorite"></span>
            {{show.title}} 
            <span class="badge">{{show.year}}</span>
            <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-edit"></i>
        </li>
    </ul>

    <select class="form-control pull-right" ng-model="main.order" ng-options="order as order.title for order in main.orders"></select>
    <div class="clearfix"></div>
    </br>
    <div class="row">
            <div class="col-xs-6"></div>
            <div class="col-xs-6">
                <a href="./add.html"><button class = "btn-primary pull-right">New Show</button></a>
            </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: What happens when you hit the URL /add?

Comment: The application gets routed to add.html, and this page gets opened. The issue is that on this page I am not able to access my controller.

Comment: did you get any errors in the console?? Also can I please ask what version of AngularJS you are using because ControllerAs syntax was not in the earlier versions of AngularJS. This may not be your issue though.

Comment: angularjs/1.5.0-beta.2/angular.min.js  and angularjs/1.2.25/angular-route.js

Comment: let me know your email id, I will send you my project. The 2 problems are that I am not able to access controller from add.html page and gives error if I use angular.module('app').config in config.js page.

Comment: Could you create a plunk instead on plunkr.co that way more people can assist you? Also its helpful to put the error in your questions for others to see.

Comment: I have created a plunk. the url is http://plnkr.co/edit/f7DDVkdOv7gQSCZaGNsc?p=preview. Could you please check and help me out.

Comment: I've forked a new plunk and submitted it, hope it helps. Let us know if you don't understand anything. Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

Currently you have directly added the content inside the body. I think that html should be belong to `add.html`. and while loading that content directly doesn't load controller `MainController` with alias `main`.

As you want to see the changes on the page `ngRoute` then you need to have `ng-view` directive on your page. Which will add `add.html` content on the page dynamically.

**Markup**

```
<body style="width: 60%; margin:0 auto;">
    <ng-view></ng-view>
</body>
```

**Add.html**

```
<h1>This is add page.</h1>
<h3>Add a new TV Show</h3>
{{main.title}}
{{main.shows[0].title}}
<form name="main.addForm" class="form" ng-submit="main.addShow()">

    <div class="form-group">
        <label>Title</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" ng-model="main.new.title" required />
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label>Year</label>
        <input type="number" min="1900" max="2030" class="form-control" ng-model="main.new.year" required />
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-6">
            <label>Favorite: <input type="checkbox" ng-model="main.new.favorite" /></label>
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-6">
            <button class="btn btn-success pull-right"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus-sign"></span> Add</button>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

Also you should have `controllerAs: 'main'` in default route

```
$routeProvider
.when('/',{
    templateUrl: 'index.html',
    controller: 'MainController',
    controllerAs: 'main'
})
```

Comment: Hi, I tried what you have suggested, but it didn't work. I have updated the code with all the files in my project. Could you please tell me that where am I going wrong.

Answer (score 0):

I've provided an updated [plunkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/jEeQ3u4zmoAlDRnPFNiU?p=preview) as requested. Please have a look at it. A few things I've noticed and provide some tips.:

**Avoid Globals**

Try and use **IIFE** functions to wrap your module references, instead of leaving it in the global namespace.

```
angular.module("app", ["ngRoute"]; // Your code
```

**Suggestion**

```
(function() {
    "use strict";
     angular.module("app", ["ngRoute"];
})();
```

**$locationProvider.html5Mode(true) not $locationProvider.HTML5Mode(true);**

```
(function() {
    angular
        .module("app")
        .config(function($routeProvider, $locationProvider) {

           // $locationProvider.HTML5Mode(true); <-- your code
           $locationProvider.html5Mode(true);
           .... // rest of code
        });
})();
```

You tried to reference the angular module using **app** variable in the **config.js** file but app was never defined, again if you use an **IIFE** you can reference it.

```
app.config(...) // app was not defined, had a reference error.
```

You can reference it like so:

```
(function () {
    "use strict";

     angular
         .module("app")
         .config(function() {

         });
})();
```

Please let me know if this is what you want, I'll keep updating as needed. Also I've provided [John Papa's style guide link](https://github.com/johnpapa/angular-styleguide), its really good and backed by the Angular team, have a look. I learnt a lot from it.

Comment: Thank you so much for your help. I will definately check the style guide link. But still when I move to add.html page and try to access controller objects and methods, I am not able to access. There is a piece of code in add.html
`{{main.title}}
 {{main.shows[0].title}}`
Still I am not able to access it.

Comment: @vishesh add this line to the body tag and you should see it: `data-ng-controller="MainController as main"`, also I recommend you look into the ng-view and routing module properly. The way you have it setup is not very ideal. The other alternative is to look at `ui-router` another routing module for Angular.